# Play-Morphia with Play 1.4

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, playframework-1.x, morphia

I'm trying to use Play-Morphia with my Play Framework app. So far I've installed the module with `play install morphia` and my application dependencies.yml looks something like this:

```
# Application dependencies

require:
    - play
    - play -> morphia 1.2.12
```

And finally `play deps --sync`.

I've followed every guideline available at this point but nothing seems to work, my `import play.modules.morphia` never resolves. Play only picks up docviewer as being a valid module. Can anyone give me some insight into what I am doing wrong?

I'm using play 1.4.1 and play-morphia 1.2.12.

Answer (score 0):

Try add your play-morphia dependency follow the instruction listed here: https://gist.github.com/greenlaw110/2868365